# Bundle and use in another file

Tags: javascript, browserify, reactjs, material-ui

I want use material-ui.com in my react site.But i cant understand how add to my asp.net site.

I bundle with browserify.But i cant use it in my other pages.I take error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined .

```js
var CalisanIslemListesi = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.func
    },
 
    render:function(){
        return (<p><RaisedButton /></p>);
    }
});
```

My bundle file http://www.filedropper.com/materialuibundle

Answer (score 0):

This was a very common problem for me too. This happens because MaterialUI needs some basic styles in order to work. You can find them here: http://material-ui.com/#/get-started

So unless you add these style to all components that use material-ui, it'll show the above error because it is looking for a dependency that is not available. If you go to the link above, it'll show you what styles it needs. However, it becomes very tedious to include those styles everytime, in every component that I make.

I use React Mixins. They're BASICALLY partial components that you can add to your component code. When you add a mixin to a component, what effectively happens is, the mixin gets expanded and added to your component. A lot like variables in string concatenation (Horrible example, I know, but it'll help you understand). When you add a variable to a string concatenation, the variable effectively gets replaced by its value. That is what happens with React Mixins.

Here is what I like to do:

Define a material.jsx file in my directory that goes like this (It is basically copied from their getting started page):

```
var React = require('react'),
    mui = require('material-ui'),
    ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager(),
    injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");

injectTapEventPlugin();

module.exports = {
    childContextTypes: {
        muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    getChildContext: function() {
        return {
            muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
        };
    }
}
```

The above is just a mixin, it contains all styles required by Material-UI to function properly.
Now I'll just use the above module as a mixin in all Material-UI components.

```
var React = require('react'),
    material = require('./material.jsx'),
    mui = require('material-ui'),
    FlatButton = mui.FlatButton

module.exports = React.createClass({
    mixins: [material],

    render: function() {
        return <FlatButton>Hello</FlatButton>
    }
})
```

In your code, if you make this material.jsx file and add the line mixins: [material] like I did, it'll all start working :)